# If Q is an orthogonal matrix, does it follow that $QDQ^T = Q^TDQ$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say A is a real, $n \times n$ symmetric matrix. Then it is orthogonally diagonalisable, with $A = QDQ^T = QDQ^{-1}$.

Let's say we do not know that Q is symmetric (at first) - does the above hold?

Comment: $Q$ will most often *not* be symmetric!  Cheers!

Comment: If $Q$ is symmetric, then $Q=Q^T$ and the answer to your question should be obvious. If $Q$ is not symmetric, why don't you try a few random examples (e.g. using permutation matrices) to see whether the statement is true or not?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a concrete example. Take 
$$Q = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1\end{array}\right]$$
and
$$D = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{array}\right].$$
Then $D$ is diagonal and $Q$ orthogonal but
$$A = QDQ^T = \frac{1}{2}\left[\begin{array}{cc} 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 3\end{array}\right]$$
and
$$Q^TDQ = \frac{1}{2}\left[\begin{array}{cc} 3 & -1 \\ -1 & 3\end{array}\right]$$
So the answer to your question is no.

Comment: I really wish people would *just try things out* sometimes; it's not like failed experiments in mathematics will blow up in your face.

Answer (score 0):

Q is orthogonal, it does not implies that it is symmetric.
Q is in $O(n)$
You have : $Q*Q^T = I_n$, that is : $Q^T = Q^{-1}$.

Comment: Please edit your answer such that the formula is more readable. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference